# Javascript Event Object

Tags: javascript

In traditional event registration model:

```
function foo(e){console.log(e.type)}
document.getElementById("#id").onclick=foo;//registered event handler
```

But in inline event registration model:

```
<a href="#" onclick=foo(event)>clck</a>  

console.log(a.click)===function click(){foo(event)}
```

Can't event object be used directly within the function *foo* rather than pass as a function argument.Since event object being used within the click function is not passed by the browser we are manually passing it.Why passing event object within the event handler function dont work?

Comment: `event` isn't defined in the global context which is how you are trying to access it to pass it to your function. Anyway, don't use inline events.

Comment: `event` is defined in global context in some browsers (Internet Exporter, IIRC). Attributes do need to be quoted, though. @Maizere, you're counting on the help of random strangers who aren't getting paid to help you. Try waiting more than 18 minutes before you start complaining that no one has answered you yet - especially when it's the middle of the night in America, where many of SO's users are.

Comment: exaxtly, don't use inline events :) but try setting `foo("bar")` and you should receive `bar` in your function as a parameter.

Comment: @Mathletics i was asking for the reason .There can be cases where we need inline event registration model

Comment: @Maizere I very much doubt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since event object being used within the click function is not passed by the browser we are manually passing it.

That's not correct. The browser (at least W3C compatible browser) pass the event object to the event handler.

The equivalent to

```
onclick="foo()"
```

is

```
elem.onclick = function(event) {
    foo();
};
```

The browser creates a function with `event` as first parameter and uses the value of the attribute as body of the function.

**You have to pass the event object explicitly to `foo` because that's how JavaScript functions work**. If you call a function inside another function, the outer function's parameters are *not* automatically passed to the inner function (that would be really confusing IMO).
Simpler example:

```
function foo(a) {
    bar();
}

function bar(a) {
    alert(a); // will show `undefined`
}

foo(42);
```

Comment: what will happen if i declare a var event in window context or within the function itself,will this declararion makes difference

Comment: You might want to provide a proper example, I would say no, it won't make a difference (as in it won't give you access to the event object).