# Preventing event propagation

Tags: javascript

```
  function foos()
  {
    return false;
  }

  function foo()
   {
     concole.log("Maizere");
   }


<div onclick="foo()">
    <button type="button" onclick="return foos()">Display Date</button>
</div>
```

Return false is not cancelling the event propagation ,but is said that it also prevents event propagation. Have i misunderstood it?

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) is the reference

Comment: have you tried event.preventdefault()  and event.cancelbubble = true

Comment: @SatpalSingh that is not my problem ,i m willing to know why return false is not working

Comment: Where did you find that return false prevents propagation?

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the event object parameter in the `foos` function, you can call `stopPropagation()` on it:

```
  function foos(ev)
  {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
```

Returning false on vanilla javascript event handlers won't prevent propagation. However, jQuery event handlers will prevent it.

Return false here, will prevent default behavious, such as navigation when pressing a link or submitting a form with a submit button.

Comment: i was willing to know why return false is not working as it has been said

Comment: Return false prevents default behavior, but it won't prevent propagation.

Comment: it also prevents event propatation

Comment: i have provided the link plz check it out

Comment: See my remark about the jQuery event handlers. Your example doesn't use jQuery, and thus `stopPropagation` isn't happening.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you're happy with the solution you should accept or upvote.

Comment: i would be thankful if u help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333390/javascript-event-object) problem.I have accepted and upvoted ur post